# JAR and EAR Import Error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jar, ear

For some reason i keep getting import error as shown in the snapshot. Do you have any idea idea on how to solve the import error?

Note: same problem occurs when i try to import JAR file.

[image]

Comment: check exactly which class is giving a NoClassDefFoundError.. this article can help you http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html

Answer (score 0):

`NOClassDefFoundError`: Find out which classes it is (It seems some portlet specific class) and find out which jar has that class file and add that jar to classpath.